# AJAX - Double Results on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have this bit of code where it displays some locations from an XML feed using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testxml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find("Country[Name='"+localStorage.ArrivalCountry+"']").find('Destination').each(function(){
            var destinationName = $(this).attr('Name');
            $('<a class="listItem" href="#" id="'+destinationName+'">'+destinationName+x+'<div class="arrow"></div></a>').appendTo('#destinationList');
        });

    }
});
```

First time it displays correctly but if I refresh the page it displays each result two times. If I do it again it displays it three times and so on.

Comment: what does your Ajax call return??? give us an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `empty()` the previous AJAX calls' data from the `#destinationList` before you add the updated set:

```javascript
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "testxml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $("#destinationList").empty(); // This will clear out all the previously appended 'a' elements
        $(xml).find("Country[Name='"+localStorage.ArrivalCountry+"']").find('Destination').each(function() {
            var destinationName = $(this).attr('Name');
            $('<a class="listItem" href="#" id="'+destinationName+'">'+destinationName+x+'<div class="arrow"></div></a>').appendTo('#destinationList');
        });
    }
});
```

More information about [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: He wrote he refreshes the page, so due the stateless of web application, there is no need for it. If I understood him right.

Comment: Thanks. Solved the problem :D